# Derivative of an univalent function

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the derivative of a univalent function cannot be zero. But I am wondering if a function has non zero derivative, then is it univalent?
Under what conditions the converse is true?

Comment: Counter example: e^z

Comment: That correct. Under what conditions the converse is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ analytic in the unit disc and locally univalent ($f'(z) \ne 0$ anywhere); then consider the Schwarzian derivative $S(f)(z)= \frac{d}{dz}({\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}})-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)})^2$.

Nehari's theorem says that if $|S(f)(z)| \le 2(1-|z|^2)^{-2}$ for all $|z|<1$, then $f$ is univalent and $2$ is best constant for which the result holds (there are counterexamples for all constants bigger than $2$)

(Conversely, it is known that for all univalent functions in the disc, the inequality above is satisfied with $6$ instead of $2$ and again that is best possible)

Answer (score 3):

The only holomorphic univalent functions from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ are those of the form $z\mapsto az+b$, with $a\neq0$, and they all have non-zero derivative everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are many results (necessary, sufficient, etc) on univalence of holomorphic functions. The most famous is probably [Bieberbach Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Branges%27s_theorem), proven by de Branges, which is a neccessary condition for univalence:

**Theorem.**  If a power series $z+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nz^n$ defines a univalent function in the unit disk then
$$
|a_n|\le n, \forall n\ge 2. 
$$

Remarkably, there is also a **necessary and sufficient** condition for univalence of a holomorphic function defined in the unit disk; the condition has the form of an infinite set of inequalities, called   [Grunsky inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunsky_matrix).

There are several books on univalent function (it used to be a very active area of research in complex analysis), for instance,

P. Duren,  Univalent functions, Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften, 259, Springer-Verlag, 1983.